# Hide the cell selection box in Excel

Tags: excel, cursor, cell, selection, highlight

I was wondering if there was any way to hide which cell you have selected within excel (for presentation purposes). I want the cursor itself (to navigate), but I want the box that highlights which cell i am clicking on invisible if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: No there is not

Comment: A solution would be (using Excel-vba) to have an image hovering on top of the Excel Sheet.  It looks quite complicate to operate.  Why do you need the selected cell to be actually selected?

Comment: Well, I don't highlight any cell. At the moment, I have a worksheet that's supposed to look like a webpage control panel with buttons on it. However, each time i click on a button, the cell highlights itself with a box - giving away the fact that i am actually using excel.

Comment: To "hide" the selection box if you *don't* need to otherwise navigate/scroll around the worksheet (and to "lock" the visible top-left set of cells in place) you could use something like `Range("A1").Select: ActiveSheet.ScrollArea = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Address: Cells(500, 500).Select`.  It prevents scrolling with [`ScrollArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.scrollarea) and selects a cell far outside of the allowable scroll area (which is the [`visibleRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.window.visiblerange)).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a button object on your worksheet, it shouldn't highlight any cell.  If you're using a cell as a "button", your best bet would be to hide and not use column A on your worksheet and then create a module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

which will select the now hidden cell A1, and hopefully no one notices...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of to hide the box around the ActiveCell. However, you can create the same end result by placing the ActiveCell off screen (out of site of the user) and scrolling to the section of the screen that you want the user to see.

Cells(1000, 10000).Select 'Selects a cell that's far from the working area
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1 'scrolls to Column 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'scrolls to Column 2

Now you've got a nice clear sheet without the selected cell box cluttering things up.

Answer (score -1):

What I do is put the Selection Box in a Hidden Range. That effectively "hides" it from the user, because it is part of a range that cannot be seen.